# Cannot profile my app using Flash Builder 4

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I am having trouble profiling my application using Flash Builder 4 with any version of Flash Player above 10.0 (approximately, I can't remember exactly).  To get round this I installed an older version of Flash player for IE and pointed the profiler to this when profiling.  Now I want to use 10.3 so this is a problem!  The alert box I receive is:

"Unable to connect to the application to fetch profile data.
Please try profiling the application again."

Hope someone can help?

Thanks

Chris

*** EDIT, Answer ***

It turns out I needed to state a full path to the ProfilerAgent.swf in my workspace in the mm.cfg in my home directory.  For example:

PreloadSwf=C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Working folder\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\com.adobe.flash.profiler\ProfilerAgent.swf?debug=true

Comment: Are you using the Debug version or the standard player....?

Comment: agreed w/ above, www.playerversion.com

Comment: Are you running any kind of low end heuristic anti virus or firewall? And which version of IE are you using. I find IE9 works well with profiler. And are you launching normally or using the debug mode of flex. a Straight play button would not always work.

Comment: When you press the Play button the player does not bother to broadcast certain things, when you click the bug looking button (debug mode) it broad casts far more information. 


To be honest you could just make a component that profiles in your app that appears via a hot key.

See this little piece of sexy:

http://flexponential.com/2010/02/21/memory-graph-to-track-flash-player-total-memory-usage/

Comment: Assuming that's the sort of profiling you want to do...
There are som many things you can watch track monitor and manage in the debug and profiler modes it really depends what you want to monitor.

Comment: I found this hugely valuable http://www.slideshare.net/jwilker/jun-heider-flex-application-profiling-by-example

Answer (score 0):

If IE fails you, try using Chrome or Firefox. For chrome, ensure you are using the latest Flash Player Debug version. You can check by typing "about:plugins" in the address bar. Ensure you are NOT using the one that comes bundled with Chrome.

Comment: I have tried all three and the stand alone Flash Player, uninstalling and reinstalling all versions of Flash Player for all formats and allowing Flash Player through anti virus and firewalls!  This is an annoying bug from Adobe!